# *.less syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: css, less, syntax-highlighting, geany

Is there any way to add syntax highlighting for *.less files in Geany? I found that using *.css syntax higlighting, sugessted somewhere in the internet is not enough for me, and in fact it making bloody mess from any more complicated *.less stylesheet.

I really like Geany, so changing IDE is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "bloody mess" might be a little exaggerated, no ? I have no big problem myself using css coloring in geany. BTW I also use shortcuts to compile .less into .css from geany.

Comment: Maybe a little, but comments "// comment" that don't stand out in code can be very irritating for me especially in bigger files.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/344441/less-syntax-highlighting-in-geany (use the highlighter for CSS code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to write your own highlighting.

In this case you should edit file `filetype_extensions.conf`, create a file `filetype.less` (see other filetypes for examples, preferably those similar to .less - like .css) and maybe play around with `filetype.conf`.

On the other hand, if you never work with .css files, you could just edit corresponding configuration files to set up the highlighting you would enjoy.

If this is still not enough, you may have take another editor (with designed highlighting for .less files), see how the highlighting is organised there and then reproduce it with geany.

This may be overcomplicated solution, though I don't insist it's the only one.

Comment: It is pretty good solution, but i was hoping for easier way to obtain desired effect. But if there will be no other answer I will accept this.

Comment: As I've said, I don't pretend this to be the best solution, but this is the best thing I was able to think off (I've had to do something similar once) and this is probably better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

On Geany menu: Tools -> Configurations Files -> filetype_extensions.conf

Change:

```
CSS=*.css;
```

With:

```
CSS=*.css;*.scss;*.less;
```

And your *.less file will be highlighted enough to start to work

Comment: Worker for me! :)